# Get value of static field from annotation

Tags: kotlin, annotations, annotation-processor

I would like to get value from static field from the declared annotation.
Example:

```
@TestAnnotation
const val MY_CUSTOM_FIELD = "test123"
```

and I would like to get "test123" as value.

So far I can get the name and kind from `Element` like this:

```
for (element: Element in environment?.getElementsAnnotatedWith(TestAnnotation::class.java)!!) {
   if (element.kind != ElementKind.FIELD) {
      messager?.error("@TestAnnotation must be applied to field")
      return true
   }
   val typeMirror = element.asType()
   messager?.error(elements?.getName(element.simpleName).toString()) // this prints MY_CUSTOM_FIELD
   messager?.error(typeMirror.toString()) // this prints java.lang.String
}
```

is it possible somehow to get "test123"?

Comment: Just to note: Ensuring the annotation is present on a field should not be necessary if the `@Target` annotation only specifies fields; normal compiler checks will catch if the annotation is not on a field. That being said, it may help to validate the field is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`VariableElement#getConstantValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/VariableElement.html#getConstantValue()):

> Returns the value of this variable if this is a `final` field initialized to a compile-time constant. Returns `null` otherwise. The value will be of a primitive type or a `String`. If the value is of a primitive type, it is wrapped in the appropriate wrapper class (such as [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html)).
>
> Note that not all `final` fields will have constant values. In particular, `enum` constants are *not* considered to be compile-time constants. To have a constant value, a field's type must be either a primitive type or `String`.
>
> **Returns:**
>   the value of this variable if this is a `final` field initialized to a compile-time constant, or `null` otherwise
>
> **See *Java Language Specification*:**
>      [15.28 Constant Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)
>      [4.12.4 final Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

You'll have to cast the `Element` to a `VariableElement`. For example:

```
for (element: Element in environment?.getElementsAnnotatedWith(TestAnnotation::class.java)!!) {
   if (element.kind != ElementKind.FIELD) {
      messager?.error("@TestAnnotation must be applied to field")
      return true
   }
   val constant = (element as VariableElement).constantValue;
}
```

Note that since `element.kind == ElementKind.FIELD` the cast to `VariableElement` will work.